# Calling Python Script from Kbuild file

Tags: python, linux-kernel, kbuild

How can I call a python script present in scripts folder from the Kbuild file?
There is a code to call shell script from the Kbuild as follows :

```
#####
# 4) Check for missing system calls
#

always += missing-syscalls
targets += missing-syscalls

quiet_cmd_syscalls = CALL    $<
      cmd_syscalls = $(CONFIG_SHELL) $< $(CC) $(c_flags) $(missing_syscalls_flags)

missing-syscalls: scripts/checksyscalls.sh $(offsets-file) FORCE
        $(call cmd,syscalls)
```

Similarly, I wanted to call a python script that takes three arguments as input.

Comment: KBuild file is actually a Makefile, so all Make constructions are available.

Comment: @Tsyvarev can you please tell the syntax or any reference for calling a python script from Kbuild file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to call a script when target `missing-syscalls` is processed, then add a line like `script.py arg1 arg2 arg3` as a receipt (tab-indented line) for that target. See more about receitps in a Makefile here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you so much. It worked !!